# display list based on the conditional listview statement in django views using the same template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I want to display the list of requests based on a particular fruit of interest. so i wrote a list view with the condition that it should display list which includes mango otherwise, it should display list that includes banana. so when i render the template, the template should check if its mango_list or banana_list.but only mango_list displays. the else statement in views doesn't work

i wrote the conditional statement in views to render mango_list if the context is mango_list else display banana_list. And put the condition in template.

Here is my code below

views.py

```
def fruit_list_view(request):
    mango_list = Request.objects.filter(taste__icontains='mango')
    banana_list = Request.objects.filter(taste__icontains='banana')
    context ={
        'mango_list': mango_list,
        'banana_list': banana_list,
        }
    if mango_list in context.values():
        return render(request,"frCat_list.html",context={'mango_list': mango_list})
    else:
        return render(request,"frCat_list.html",context={'banana_list': banana_list})
```

url.py

```
urlpatterns = [

    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('mango_list/', views.fruit_list_view, name='mango_list'),
    path('banana_list/', views.fruit_list_view, name='banana_list'),
]
```

template file (template name is frCat_list.html)

```
{% extends 'base_generic.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}


<body>
{% if mango_list %}
    {% for request in mango_list %}
  <tbody> 

      <td><a href="{% url 'request-detail' request.id %}">{{request.id}}</a></td>
      <td>{{request.price}}</td>
      <td>{{request.size}}</td>
      <td>{{request.comment}}</td>

  </tbody>
  {% endfor %}
  </table>
{% elif banana_list %}
    {% for request in banana_list %}
  <tbody> 

      <td><a href="{% url 'request-detail' request.id %}">{{request.id}}</a></td>
      <td>{{request.colour}}</td>
      <td>{{request.size}}</td>
      <td>{{request.comment}}</td>

  </tbody>
  {% endfor %}
  </table>

  {% else %}
    <p>There are no such fruit available.</p>
  {% endif %}

</body>      

{% endblock %}
```

i expect to see the conditional statement work in my template. That when its mango_list the list of requests including manago will display and when its banana_list, the list of requests including banana will display. But only mango list works. Please help....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify that by passing parameters from the `url(..)`. First we can define the view function like:

```
def fruit_list_view(request, taste):
    context = {
        '{}_list'.format(taste): Request.objects.filter(taste__icontains=taste)
    }
    return render(request,"frCat_list.html",context=context)
```

and then in the `urls.py`, we can pass the value for `taste` to the [**`url(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urls/#django.urls.url):

```
# app/urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('mango_list/', views.fruit_list_view, kwargs={'taste': 'mango'}, name='mango_list'),
    path('banana_list/', views.fruit_list_view, kwargs={'taste': 'banana'}, name='banana_list'),
]
```

In your template please do *not* name a variable `request`, since Django passes a variable with the name `request` to the template. Since the two look very similar, it might be better to use one name for the products, and disambiguate in a different way.

It seems to make more sense however to simply always use the same variable `list`, and always render with that list, like:

```
def fruit_list_view(request, taste):
    context = {
        'item_list': Request.objects.filter(taste__icontains=taste)
    }
    return render(request,"frCat_list.html",context=context)
```

In the template we can then render this with:

```
<body>
{% if list %}
    {% for item in item_list %}
  <tbody> 

      <td><a href="{% url 'request-detail' item.id %}">{{item.id}}</a></td>
      <td>{{item.price}}</td>
      <td>{{item.size}}</td>
      <td>{{item.comment}}</td>

  </tbody>
  {% endfor %}
  </table>
{% endif %}
</body>
```

Comment: Your comment on the template concerning the "request" is well noted. Than you!

Comment: how can i reduce the code in the template since will be iterating over a lot of querysets. i tried the below which didnt work.

Comment: combined_list = list(chain('mango_list', 'banana_list')                                                         and my template is below
  
  {% for sr in combined_list %}
     {% if mango_list or banana_list %} 
  <tbody> 
    
      <td><a href="{% url 'request-detail' request.id %}">{{request.id}}</a></td>
      <td>{{request.price}}</td>
      <td>{{request.size}}</td>
      <td>{{request.comment}}</td>
    {% else %}
    <p>There are no available service request.</p>
  {% endif %}
  
{% endfor %}
</body>      
{% endblock %}

Comment: @betty: why not just always set a variable `list`, and thus always render this with `{% for item in list %} {{ item.id }} {{ item.price }} ... {% endfor %}`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. in views.py file when i use    list=[mango_list, banana_list], it says mango_list not defined. when i define   list=['{}_list'.format(skill)]  
 in the fruit_list_view function nothing displays

Comment: @betty: but there is no need to combine these, just always define a *single* list named `item_list` for example. See updated example.

Comment: Thanks so much Willem Van Onsem . You are a Genius!!